# Is there an AI that is capable of DMing using the 1983 Mentzer Basic DnD rules?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, tools, online-resources, dnd-becmi

I'd like to solo play using the 1983 Mentzer Basic DnD rules (red box). Is there an AI that can deploy the rule set if I provide dice rolls and do the record keeping? Either published modules or something procedurally generated would be fine. Nothing on character AI worked. I prefer war gamey and stat based play, not chatty role play. Thanks

Comment: I would encourage members to view this as a question about the state of the technology, rather than a specific product request.

Answer (score 9):

### As of November 2023, not in a satisfying way.

First, it is always hard to answer a question that asks "does X exist" in the negative. But in this case, the current state of the art is fairly well known as it applies to this question. Second, this is based on the present in a field that changes very, very rapidly. As of November 2023 the answer is no, but this answer will likely be obsolete soon.

But in my opinion, no currently available AI can provide a remotely satisfying experience acting as a DM even for 5E DND and using an older edition where there is less written material available online to be in the training set would almost certainly be even worse.

I have, just out curiosity, tried using the currently available AI systems as DMs for solo campaigns in 5e. It was not remotely satisfying. All of them were inconsistent, failed to track the state of game, made rules, and story mistake. All of this is true to a degree of human DMs of course, but I mean it did all of these things badly and from the very beginning.

This result is not surprising when you think about how they work. In simplified terms, they are not really trying to answer anything with understanding. They are using neural networks, which at their heart are statistics and linear algebra, to generate things that look like an answer to the prompt. They get [facts wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1fl9byDtfg&t=16s) all the time and they are creative only in the sense that they do create things that a human would not be likely to create.

They are very good at making up nonsense. They are not good at holding a lengthy, coherent, conversation which is required for DMing.

I very much expect this answer to change soon, but in the meantime, based both on my experience and my understanding of how they work, I do not think any present AI can substitute for even a mediocre human DM.

Comment: Agree.  I was in the process of doing the experiment, and am getting the same results using ChatGPT4

Comment: "They are very good at making up nonsense." To be fair, that's why I also thought about using AI :D. I'm really bad at making up nonsense, and so I make a lousy DM.

Comment: It can definitely be valuable to spend time with an AI and see what they can make up, but you'll have to distill the usable parts out of that yourself, and probably shuffle it around a bit to make it make sense. So as a tool, it can be useful. That is, however, not the scope of the question.